# App is crashed on launch by app store reviewed

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I've tested my apps with all sort of iOs version and result is working fine on those devices. But when I published to App Store, they rejected that **app is crashed on launch**. I cannot convince why app is crashed on their phone even I've tested with same iOs version.

Please let me know, how to solve that issue and I've attached error logs.

```
{"app_name":"CakeApp","timestamp":"2017-08-10 06:54:09.29 -0700","app_version":"3","slice_uuid":"ba63de93-382a-3879-933d-e584d00cb7aa","adam_id":1233988265,"build_version":"1.2","bundleID":"com.ppshein.CakeApp","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)","incident_id":"81B4B45E-ACB0-4305-81BE-B88E4E257238","name":"CakeApp"}
Incident Identifier: 81B4B45E-ACB0-4305-81BE-B88E4E257238
CrashReporter Key:   318083a7319cbe05fd01b4c953a58aebe938f998
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             CakeApp [5822]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/126924F1-2DBF-4F12-8355-1C5787680F75/CakeApp.app/CakeApp
Identifier:          com.ppshein.CakeApp
Version:             1.2 (3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.ppshein.CakeApp [1034]


Date/Time:           2017-08-10 06:54:09.0262 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-08-10 06:54:06.9573 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001002749c8
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CakeApp                     0x00000001002749c8 0x100098000 + 1952200
1   CakeApp                     0x000000010026dca4 0x100098000 + 1924260
2   UIKit                           0x00000001930eae48 0x19306a000 + 527944
3   UIKit                           0x00000001932f737c 0x19306a000 + 2675580
4   UIKit                           0x00000001932fce24 0x19306a000 + 2698788
5   UIKit                           0x00000001933118b0 0x19306a000 + 2783408
6   UIKit                           0x00000001932fa0b8 0x19306a000 + 2687160
7   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018eaf8884 0x18eabe000 + 239748
8   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018eaf86f0 0x18eabe000 + 239344
9   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018eaf8aa0 0x18eabe000 + 240288
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cefd42c 0x18ce22000 + 898092
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cefcd9c 0x18ce22000 + 896412
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cefa9a8 0x18ce22000 + 887208
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ce2ada4 0x18ce22000 + 36260
14  UIKit                           0x00000001930e3fc8 0x19306a000 + 499656
15  UIKit                           0x00000001930dec9c 0x19306a000 + 478364
16  CakeApp                     0x00000001000a5e3c 0x100098000 + 56892
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018be3959c 0x18be35000 + 17820
```

Comment: Did you test the Testflight version before submitting app on app store? Sometimes app doesn't behave the same in release environment.

Comment: Obviously impossible to be sure since there's not nearly enough info here, but from the trace, I'd hazard a guess that you're using Swift and it's a crash on launch, force-unwrapping an optional in a method called from `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)`. As for reproducing, like Palle's answer says, delete the app (if it's a testing device, like it should be, wipe it completely), and install the testflight/beta version.

Answer (score 2):

Did you test your app in a clean environment? Uninstall the app and delete all of its data and then install again.

You can try to resolve the crash by symbolicating the stack trace, as described in [this technical note from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATEWITHXCODE), which can help you identify the part of your code that crashed.